# Why the use of the plural form in describing the mincha for the 7th day of Succot?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, pinchas

In the description of the Succot sacrifices in B'midbar 29:12-39, when describing the mincha for days 2-6 the phrasing is in singular at the end of the verse as in:

וּמִנְחָתָ֣ם וְנִסְכֵּיהֶ֡ם לַ֠פָּרִים לָאֵילִ֧ם וְלַכְּבָשִׂ֛ים בְּמִסְפָּרָ֖ם **כַּמִּשְׁפָּֽט׃**

However, for the 7th day (verse 33) it is phrased in plural:

וּמִנְחָתָ֣ם וְנִסְכֵּהֶ֡ם לַ֠פָּרִים לָאֵילִ֧ם וְלַכְּבָשִׂ֛ים בְּמִסְפָּרָ֖ם **כְּמִשְׁפָּטָֽם**׃

Why the difference for the 7th day?

Comment: See [*Ta'anis* 2b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=10&daf=2b&format=text), where R' Yehuda ben Beseira uses this as part of an allusion to the water libation.